# Retrieve several overlapping matches from a string in PyParsing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyparsing

I have

```
s = '10001001110100000'
```

I want to extract all matches (`'0'`s between `'1'`s including the `'1'`s from the edges). The result should be `[10001, 1001, 101]` for this example.

I coded a simple expression using PyParsing but I'm surprised how difficult it is to find a solution since PyParsing is returning the first match only.

My code so far:

```
from pyparsing import Group, OneOrMore, ZeroOrMore

s = '10001001110100000'
expr = ('1' + OneOrMore('0') + '1')
rule = ZeroOrMore(Group(expr))
print(rule.parseString(str).asList())
```

Which yields:

```
[['1', '0', '0', '0', '1']]
```

Expected result:

```
['10001', '1001', '101']
```

How to get other matches?

This question is specific to PyParsing.

Comment: Why not just iterate through the string and extract them?

Comment: I want to use pyparsing. I know how to do it with regex etc. but this is an exercise for me, so... Or you mean iterate and then parse with pyparsing?

Comment: It actually sounds like an exercise for *us*...

Comment: @MarkMeyer -:) I'm still trying here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A naive approach is to loop and keep track of the last `"1"` as you move through the list:

```
s = '10001001110100000'
res = []
last_i = s.find('1')

for i in range(last_i, len(s)):
    if s[i] == '1':
        if i - last_i > 1:
            res.append(s[last_i:i+1])

        last_i = i

print(res) # => ['10001', '1001', '101']
```

Regex is not suitable for tasks such as this because the matches overlap but `PyParsing` appears to have an overlap option on the [`ParserElement#scanString`](https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing.ParserElement-class.html#scanString) method:

```
from pyparsing import Group, OneOrMore, ZeroOrMore

s = '10001001110100000'
rule = ZeroOrMore(Group(('1' + OneOrMore('0') + '1')))
print(list(rule.scanString(s, overlap=True)))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to do it without PyParsing. The question is specific to PyParsing.

Comment: OK, added a PyParsing version.

Comment: Nice one. Thanks. I missed the "overlap" flag. Always learning. I didn't try with scanstring that's why I missed the overlap.

Comment: Regarding the str. True, I forgot that for a moment. Python should at least give some warning. I had several strings, I forgot to remove the [ ].